# Questions about mAP results from YOLOv2 paper

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision, precision-recall, average-precision, yolo

In the [YOLOv2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.08242.pdf) paper, is the mAP metric displayed in  Table 3  calculated in the same way as the metric in the column '0.5' from  Table 5?

[image]

[image]